# Is it wrong (or a mess) to have ActionBarSherlock + ViewPagerIndicator + HoloEverywhere at the same time?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator, android-holo-everywhere

**Short:**
Generally I'm thinking that having the three (ABS+VPI+HE) as libraries in my project could be something redundant for what I want to achieve, maybe one includes another and there's no need to have the three libraries.

**Long:**
I am trying to make an app and I'm spending some time on its UI/UX to make it pretty nice since its functionality is almost done.

I got it working nicely with ActionBarSherlock + ViewPagerIndicator, but then I saw that on Android 2.1 compatibility some controls where old and horrible. So I discovered HoloEverywhere and added it, it was pretty cool and easy to get ABS+VPI+HE working together.

So my questions are, am I doing this the right way? Could I achieve VPI swipe effect from 2.1 to 4.2.2 with only HoloEverywhere + ActionBarSherlock? Or Could I use an ActionBar from 2.1 to 4.2.2 without ABS but with HE?

Thank you very much in advance. And sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Your English is better than a lot of "native" English speakers around here.

Comment: FWIW, Jake Wharton (author of ABS and VPI) is not a fan of HoloEverywhere: https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/319626314116132864 Neither am I, for that matter, but that's more that Android 2.x users may not recognize Holo-themed widgets for what they are.

Comment: @CommonsWare What is the reason for saying that HoloEverywhere is that bad? I've never used it, but the sample seems to work fine. Also, I wonder what google official developer have to say about this.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You would have to ask Jake why he thinks it is "crap". My reason was outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I see. The reason I ask this is because sometimes people I work with claim that in order to make the app look the same on multiple devices and look nice, we should use this library or customize everything. I just wanted to know if this library has done this nicely.

Comment: Hi, i'm main developer of HoloEverywhere. F*ck, yea, it's crap! But this crap work nice for my projects. I'm /should/ support even 1.6 sometimes...

If would not it - I would not even touched HoloEverywhere.

What do you use - it's up to you.

VPI can be replaced by PagerTabStrip/PagerTitleStrip, for example.

Comment: lol Simon, thank you! @ CommonsWare That's a reasonable argument, but I prefer bringing the full Holo experience to all people for equal than making a cool UI for people with newer devices and a standard, common and ugly UI for older devices. Your reasoning will be  the only what I'll be sacrificing. @Prototik omg, the creator of HE answering me! This was surprising :) I agree, HE works like a charm in my projects too, and your advice about VPI and PagerTabStrip/PagerTitleStrip is what I was looking for... thank you!

Comment: I use holoeverywhere and im grateful to @prototik for sharing his work with us.